# C# HashSet Generic allows duplicate

Tags: c#, hashset

Reading HashSet on MSDN, it says with `HashSet<T>`, if T implements `IEquatable<T>` then the HashSet uses this for `IEqualityComparer<T>.Default`.

So, let the class Person:

```
public class Person : IEquality<Person>
{
    private string pName;
    public Person(string name){ pName=name; }
    public string Name
    {
        get { return pName; }
        set
        {
            if (pName.Equals(value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
              return;
            }
            pName = value;
        }
    }

    public bool Equals(Person other)
    {
        if(other==null){return false;}
        return pName.Equals(other.pName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Person other = obj as Person;
        if(other==null){return false;}
        return Equals(other);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(){return pName.GetHashCode();}

    public override string ToString(){return pName;}
}
```

So, let's define in another class or main function:

```
HashSet<Person> set = new HashSet<Person>();
set.Add(new Person("Smith"); // return true
Person p = new Person("Smi");
set.Add(p); // return true
p.Name = "Smith"; // no error occurs
```

And now, you've got 2 Person objects in the HashSet with the same name (so that, there are "Equals").

HashSet let us put duplicate objects.

Answer (score 11):

> HashSet let us put duplicate objects.

It isn't letting you put in duplicate objects.  The issue is that you're *mutating* the object after it's been added.

Mutating objects being used as keys in dictionaries or stored as hashes is always problematic, and something I would recommend avoiding.

Comment: Agreed, you should consider removing the setter on Person to make Person immutable and to prevent this.