# Replace foreach with lambda

Tags: c#

Some one could you please help me out to replace foreach with lambda from below two methods or anything else optimization will be appreciated.

```
/// <summary>
/// This method will find and remove the Template entries that has no person entris
/// from List<Template> Templates
/// </summary>
/// <param name="Persons"></param>
/// <param name="Templates"></param>
public bool ClearOrphnedIDs(List<Person> Persons, List<Template> Templates)
{
    bool isClearComplete = false;
    try
    {
        if (Persons != null && Templates != null)
        {
            List<string> OrphnedTemplatesNeedToIgnore = new List<string>();
            foreach (Template template in Templates)
            {
                string personID = Persons.Find(p => p.PersonID == template.PersonID).PersonID;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(personID) && !OrphnedTemplatesNeedToIgnore.Contains(personID))
                {
                        OrphnedTemplatesNeedToIgnore.Add(template.PersonID);
                        DataSyncLog.Warn(string.Format("Templates with personID {0} is orphned (has no person entry) in DB", template.PersonID));
                }

            }
            if (OrphnedTemplatesNeedToIgnore.Count > 0)
                Templates.RemoveAll(t=> OrphnedTemplatesNeedToIgnore.Contains(t.PersonID));
            isClearComplete = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        DataSyncLog.Debug(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType + "::" + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().ToString() + " :: " + ex.Message + " :: " + ex.StackTrace);
    }
    return isClearComplete;
}

/// <summary>
/// This method will Find and remove the Person and template entries that has 
/// zero or odd number of templates. from List<Person> Persons and List<Template> Templates
/// </summary>
/// <param name="Persons"></param>
/// <param name="Templates"></param>
public bool ClearInconsistantIDs(List<Person> Persons, List<Template> Templates)
{
    bool isClearComplete = false;
    try
    {
        if (Persons != null && Templates != null)
        {
            List<string> personNeedtoIgnoreAlongWithItsTemplates = new List<string>();
            foreach (Person person in Persons)
            {
                int templatesCount = Templates.FindAll(t => t.PersonID == person.PersonID).Count;
                if (templatesCount == 0 || templatesCount % 2 != 0)
                {
                    personNeedtoIgnoreAlongWithItsTemplates.Add(person.PersonID);
                    if (templatesCount == 0)
                        DataSyncLog.Warn(string.Format("Person with Registration No: {0} and personID {1} has no Templates in DB. Templates Count: {2}", person.RegistrationNO, person.PersonID, templatesCount));
                    else
                        DataSyncLog.Warn(string.Format("Person with Registration No: {0} and personID {1} has inconsistent data (Templates) in DB. Templates Count: {2}", person.RegistrationNO, person.PersonID, templatesCount));

                }
            }
            if (personNeedtoIgnoreAlongWithItsTemplates.Count > 0)
            {
                Templates.RemoveAll(t => personNeedtoIgnoreAlongWithItsTemplates.Contains(t.PersonID));
                Persons.RemoveAll(p => personNeedtoIgnoreAlongWithItsTemplates.Contains(p.PersonID));
            }
            isClearComplete = true;
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        DataSyncLog.Debug(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType + "::" + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().ToString() + " :: " + ex.Message + " :: " + ex.StackTrace);
    }
    return isClearComplete;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think a lambda would be an optimization?

Comment: Did you try anything yourself? If not, why not? If yes, please show it and tell us what is not working. Furthermore, please only show the code *relevant to your question*

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2010/04/23/c-linq-vs-foreach---round-1.aspx

Comment: Reshaper can do this for you sometimes :)

Comment: I wrote this code. @Daniel Hilgarth and now i just ask for the change nothing else.

Comment: Honestly i don't know lamda was an optimization for this. but it looks good and i'm practicing it more rather regular code. that's why i have ask this. @Tim

Comment: -1 for no attempt on your own and for lots of irrelevant code.

Comment: Thanks. I am not very expert on lamda. but honestly i have tried. if not tried why am i suppose to post this here wasting my time? could you please convert it to lamda for me and points me out about irrelevant code if you have enough time? @DanielHilgarth

Comment: Don't take it in another way. i just want to learn the optimum solution. @DanielHilgarth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys How about this,

```
/// <summary>
    /// This method will find and remove the Template entries that has no person entris
    /// from List<Template> Templates
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Persons"></param>
    /// <param name="Templates"></param>
    public bool ClearOrphnedIDs(List<Person> Persons, List<Template> Templates)
    {
        bool isClearComplete = false;
        try
        {
            if (Persons != null && Templates != null)
            {
                HashSet<string> personsSet = new HashSet<string>(Persons.Select(p => p.PersonID));
                Templates.RemoveAll(t => !personsSet.Contains(t.PersonID));
                isClearComplete = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DataSyncLog.Debug(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType + "::" + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().ToString() + " :: " + ex.Message + " :: " + ex.StackTrace);
        }
        return isClearComplete;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method will Find and remove the Person and template entries that has 
    /// zero or odd number of templates. from List<Person> Persons and List<Template> Templates
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Persons"></param>
    /// <param name="Templates"></param>
    public bool ClearInconsistantIDs(List<Person> Persons, List<Template> Templates)
    {
        bool isClearComplete = false;
        try
        {
            if (Persons != null && Templates != null)
            {
                HashSet<string> inconsistantIDs = new HashSet<string>(
                  Persons.Select(p => p.PersonID).Where(p =>
                  {
                      var count = Templates.Count(t => t.PersonID == p);
                      return count == 0 || count % 2 != 0;
                  }
                  ));

                if (inconsistantIDs.Count > 0)
                {
                    Templates.RemoveAll(t => inconsistantIDs.Contains(t.PersonID));
                    Persons.RemoveAll(p => inconsistantIDs.Contains(p.PersonID));
                }
                isClearComplete = true;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DataSyncLog.Debug(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType + "::" + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().ToString() + " :: " + ex.Message + " :: " + ex.StackTrace);
        }
        return isClearComplete;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can do better with lambda, but you definitely can do better using `HashSet<string>` instead of `List<string>` and making another `HashSet<string>` for `PersonID` values from `Persons` parameter:

```
public bool ClearOrphnedIDs(List<Person> Persons, List<Template> Templates)
{
    bool isClearComplete = false;
    try
    {
        if (Persons != null && Templates != null)
        {
            var personsSet = new HashSet<string>(Persons.Select(p => p.PersonId));
            var orphnedTemplatesNeedToIgnore = new HastSet<string>();
            foreach (var template in Templates)
            {
                if (!personsSet.Contains(template.PersonID) && !orphnedTemplatesNeedToIgnore.Contains(personID))
                {
                        orphnedTemplatesNeedToIgnore.Add(template.PersonID);
                        DataSyncLog.Warn(string.Format("Templates with personID {0} is orphned (has no person entry) in DB", template.PersonID));
                }

            }
            if (orphnedTemplatesNeedToIgnore.Count > 0)
                Templates.RemoveAll(t => orphnedTemplatesNeedToIgnore.Contains(t.PersonID));
            isClearComplete = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        DataSyncLog.Debug(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType + "::" + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().ToString() + " :: " + ex.Message + " :: " + ex.StackTrace);
    }
    return isClearComplete;
}
```

Comment: Just reading about `HashSet` , Is it required to check `!personsSet.Contains(template.PersonID)` ??? or will can directly use `orphnedTemplatesNeedToIgnore.Add(template.PersonID);`  ??

Comment: `foreach (var template in Templates)            
                               {
                        orphnedTemplatesNeedToIgnore.Add(template.PersonID);
                        DataSyncLog.Warn(string.Format("Templates with personID {0} is orphned (has no person entry) in DB", template.PersonID));
                }` I think this will do .

Comment: So, @MarcinJuraszek you say this code is fine. Nothing need to optimize right? though if i not use the HashSet.

Comment: @surajsingh logic is if the template.PersonID does not contains in personsSet then add this to the ignorelist

Comment: @Rezoan Yup you are correct you need to check for `!PersonSet.Contains(template.PersonID)` but second condition to check `!orphnedTemplatesNeedToIgnore.Contains()` can be bypassed as it will be handled by `HashSet`  however i don't think it will affect performance or may be .

Comment: Duplicate values can be inserted from anywhere into HashSet. thats why i also need to check !orphnedTemplatesNeedToIgnore.Contains().  see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12751591/c-sharp-hashset-generic-allows-duplicate   @surajsingh

Comment: @Rezoan Well you should read full article before forwarding it ,and try something do not depend upon what you read .`HashSet` do not allows insertion of duplicate values .try this `HashSet<int> trialtwo = new HashSet<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                trialtwo.Add(i);
            }
             bool ti = Convert.ToBoolean(trialtwo.Add(5));`

Answer (score 1):

I would define an extension method `ExceptBy`

```
var result = Templates.ExceptBy(Persons, t => t.PersonID, p => p.PersonID)
                      .ToList();
```

---

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> ExceptBy<TSource, TKey, TDest>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> first,
        IEnumerable<TDest> second,
        Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector1,
        Func<TDest, TKey> keySelector2)
{
    HashSet<TKey> keys = new HashSet<TKey>(second.Select(keySelector2));

    return first.Where(k => keys.Add(keySelector1(k)));
}
```